# js for validation date range

Tags: javascript

anyone can help me....how to validate javascript date for this problem:

user select the start date and end date will be chosen to be more than 90 day from the start date.user can send form if end date below 90day...

```
from date code :
<input name="fromDate" type="text" id="fromDate" size="10" maxlength="10" onChange="">
<a href="#" name="anchorFrmDate" id="anchorFrmDate" onClick="calFrmDate.select(document.forms[0].fromDate,anchorFrmDate,'dd/MM/yyyy'); return false;">DATE</a>

to date code:
<input name="Todate" type="text" id="Todate" size="10" maxlength="10" onChange="">
a href="#" onClick="calToDte.select(document.forms[0].Todate,'anchorToDte','dd/MM/yyyy'); return false;" name="'anchorToDte'" id="'anchorToDte'"><strong>DATE</strong></a>
```

---

I've tried and my code below ... but do not succeed ... which part that i make Mistake

```
function checkDateRange(fromDate, Todate) { 
   // Parse the entries 
   var startDate = Date.parse(fromDate); 
   var endDate = Date.parse(Todate); 
   // Make sure they are valid 
    if (isNaN(startDate)) { 
      alert("The start date provided is not valid, please enter a valid date."); 
      return false; 
   } 
   if (isNaN(endDate)) { 
       alert("The end date provided is not valid, please enter a valid date."); 
       return false; 
   } 
   // Check the date range, 86400000 is the number of milliseconds in one day 
   var difference = (endDate - startDate) / (7776000000); 
   if (difference < 0) { 
       alert("The start date must come before the end date."); 
       return false; 
   } 
   if (difference <= 1) { 
       alert("The range must be at least seven days apart."); 
       return false; 
    } 
   return true; 
}
```

Comment: dup? Is the answer here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/73971/using-javascript-how-do-i-make-sure-a-date-range-is-valid

Comment: I really hope this is a homework assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a rough sketch:

```
var startDateText = ...
var NINETY_DAYS = 1000 * 3600 * 24 * 90;
var startDate = new Date(startDateText);
var maxEndDate = startDate.getTime() + NINETY_DAYS;
..
var endDateText = ...
var endDate = new Date(endDateText);
if (endDate.getTime() > maxEndDate) {
    Window.alert("Too late");
}
```