# jquery json date filter

Tags: jquery, json, sorting

We got a website that makes a json request to the server. The server returns these kind of items:

```
var items = new Array();
items[] = {
    id: 1
    date: '2011-12-01',
    time: '03:00:00'
    endDate: '2011-12-04',
    endTime: '05:00:00'
}
```

Now what I got is a date filter on the client side, so you can pick a filter and then it will only return the items matching that date. But here is the problem:

Lets say the users picks a date for example: "2011-12-02", it will ONLY look at the "date" element in the array, however if the endDate is not null (because it is not required, then the item will last one day) it has to match between those periods, so 2011-12-02 would still return the item since the begin date was 2011-12-01 and the end date was 2011-12-04 so it is between those 2 dates, so I would still have to get the item.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually have to parse those dates and check the range.

For example,

```
var myDate = new Date(2008, 9, 16);
// is myDate between Sept 1 and Sept 30?
var startDate = new Date(2008, 9, 1);
var endDate = new Date(2008, 9, 30);
if (startDate < myDate && myDate < endDate) {
    alert('yes');
    // myDate is between startDate and endDate
}
```

taken from [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73971/using-javascript-how-do-i-make-sure-a-date-range-is-valid)

hope this helps your further...

Answer (score 0):

It is very possible to do using the method suggested by fellow stacker, @randomKek. However, you may want to extend this to a large set of data. To use this method, see the following fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ladiv7/tb66ya67/

```js
/*Dummy Data, Courtesy of: https://www.generatedata.com/*/
var dataDates = [{
    "date": "Nov 28, 2017",
    "name": "Samuel A. Kidd",
    "email": "dui.nec@sapienimperdietornare.ca",
    "address": "944-343 Nec Avenue"
  },
  {
    "date": "May 20, 2015",
    "name": "Jenna R. Alston",
    "email": "semper.auctor.Mauris@acrisus.edu",
    "address": "5316 Mollis Av."
  },
  {
    "date": "Mar 11, 2018",
    "name": "Magee K. Mcfarland",
    "email": "Maecenas@egetmollis.co.uk",
    "address": "Ap #605-1298 Id Rd."
  },
  {
    "date": "Dec 9, 2016",
    "name": "Claudia V. Campbell",
    "email": "Donec@semegestas.ca",
    "address": "Ap #935-7909 Lectus Rd."
  },
  {
    "date": "Aug 4, 2015",
    "name": "Steven V. Reynolds",
    "email": "est.ac@ut.net",
    "address": "Ap #501-8119 Vel, Rd."
  },
  {
    "date": "Mar 25, 2019",
    "name": "Amy O. Bean",
    "email": "risus.quis.diam@adipiscingelitEtiam.org",
    "address": "1855 Euismod Ave"
  },
  {
    "date": "Jan 12, 2019",
    "name": "Quintessa H. Clay",
    "email": "arcu.Sed.eu@variusNam.net",
    "address": "P.O. Box 127, 812 Lobortis Rd."
  },
  {
    "date": "Feb 7, 2015",
    "name": "Marvin P. Golden",
    "email": "pellentesque@lobortistellusjusto.org",
    "address": "P.O. Box 936, 8921 Augue Av."
  },
  {
    "date": "Aug 4, 2015",
    "name": "Shay Z. Clayton",
    "email": "sem.egestas@maurisidsapien.org",
    "address": "5862 Pede St."
  },
  {
    "date": "Feb 12, 2015",
    "name": "Jin G. Jimenez",
    "email": "dictum.magna@parturientmontes.org",
    "address": "4310 Malesuada Av."
  },
  {
    "date": "Feb 10, 2017",
    "name": "Dawn R. Blackwell",
    "email": "risus.varius.orci@ipsumdolor.com",
    "address": "5585 Metus. St."
  },
  {
    "date": "Apr 28, 2015",
    "name": "Audra A. Gates",
    "email": "consectetuer.adipiscing@libero.ca",
    "address": "448-332 Iaculis Ave"
  },
  {
    "date": "May 6, 2018",
    "name": "Gloria K. Dodson",
    "email": "mauris.Integer.sem@purusinmolestie.co.uk",
    "address": "564-3879 Vel, St."
  },
  {
    "date": "Jan 1, 2015",
    "name": "Inga I. Vinson",
    "email": "Donec@enimnec.net",
    "address": "320-4632 Lacus. Road"
  },
  {
    "date": "Jul 21, 2015",
    "name": "Berk M. Owen",
    "email": "eros@mi.co.uk",
    "address": "727 Bibendum Ave"
  },
  {
    "date": "Feb 27, 2016",
    "name": "Jessica C. Thompson",
    "email": "Donec@anteNunc.com",
    "address": "P.O. Box 903, 2394 A, St."
  }
];



$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.datepicker').datepicker(); //Activates the datepicker Materialize CSS element

  preview_json(dataDates, $("#view_rawData")); //show the original data on the screen
  $("#count_RawData").html("(" + dataDates.length + ")");

  $("#filter-button").click(function(e) {

    console.log("Hello world");

    //Gets the form data in a unified manner
    var getFormData = {
      dates: {
        start: $("#date_from").val(),
        end: $("#date_to").val()
      }
    };

    //Function to filter the result
    var filteredData = dateFilterer(dataDates, getFormData.dates.start, getFormData.dates.end);
    preview_json(filteredData.finalValues, $("#view_filteredData")); //show the final result on the screen
    $("#count_FilteredData").html("(" + filteredData.finalValues.length + ")");

  });


});


//Filter function to ensure that the final result set is within a particular range
function dateFilterer(sourceValues, startDate, endDate) {

  /*Curtosy of the tutorial found here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp*/
  function filterFunction_dates(sourceValue) {

    //Aim: To test if the tested date is valid within a particular range
    var rangeAcceptance = {
      minValid: new Date(sourceValue.date) >= new Date(startDate),
      maxValid: new Date(sourceValue.date) <= new Date(endDate)
    };

    var acceptanceResult; //boolean to determine if the relevant range specified is valid

    if (startDate != "" && endDate != "") {

      acceptanceResult = (rangeAcceptance.minValid && rangeAcceptance.maxValid);

    } else if (startDate != "") {

      acceptanceResult = rangeAcceptance.minValid;

    } else if (endDate != "") {

      acceptanceResult = rangeAcceptance.maxValid;

    } else {

      acceptanceResult = (1 == 1); //show all results if no specific range has been selected

    }

    return (acceptanceResult);

  }

  /*console.log({

    originalValues: sourceValues,
    finalValues: sourceValues.filter(filterFunction_dates),
    "time of filter": new Date()

  });*/

  //Return the data for display
  return ({

    originalValues: sourceValues,
    finalValues: sourceValues.filter(filterFunction_dates)

  });

}



//Aim: To make the dates into something that the Range filter function can work with
function normalize_date(fieldValue) {

  var monthPossibilities = {
    longStructure: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"],
    shortStructure: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
  }; //To store what the month values could possibly be for returning their relevant index number

  var datePartitions = fieldValue.split(", ");
  var year = datePartitions[1];
  var month = datePartitions[0].substring(0, 3); //first three characters of section 1

  if (monthPossibilities.longStructure.indexOf(month) > -1) {

    month = (monthPossibilities.longStructure.indexOf(month) + 1).toString(); //Increments by one to give the actual month number

  } else if (monthPossibilities.shortStructure.indexOf(month) > -1) {

    month = (monthPossibilities.shortStructure.indexOf(month) + 1).toString();

  } else {

    month = "";

  }

  //Aim: Add that customary zero to prepend the date value
  if ((month.length < 2) && (month.length > 0)) {

    month = "0" + month;

  }

  var day = datePartitions[0].slice(-2); //last two characters of section 1    
  var finalResult = year + "-" + month + "-" + day;

  return (finalResult);

}




//Aim: Display json in a nicely formatted way
function preview_json(data, target) {

  /*Curtosy of fellow fiddler: http://jsfiddle.net/unLSJ/*/
  var library = {};

  library.json = {
    replacer: function(match, pIndent, pKey, pVal, pEnd) {
      var key = '<span class=json-key>';
      var val = '<span class=json-value>';
      var str = '<span class=json-string>';
      var r = pIndent || '';
      if (pKey)
        r = r + key + pKey.replace(/[": ]/g, '') + '</span>: ';
      if (pVal)
        r = r + (pVal[0] == '"' ? str : val) + pVal + '</span>';
      return r + (pEnd || '');
    },
    prettyPrint: function(obj) {
      var jsonLine = /^( *)("[\w]+": )?("[^"]*"|[\w.+-]*)?([,[{])?$/mg;
      return JSON.stringify(obj, null, 3)
        .replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/\\"/g, '&quot;')
        .replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;')
        .replace(jsonLine, library.json.replacer);
    }
  };

  //Show json in desired target
  target.html(library.json.prettyPrint(data));

}
```

```css
#count_RawData {
  color: #89cbfa;
}

#view_rawData,
#view_filteredData {
  min-height: 50px;
  max-height: 700px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #cfcfcf;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: none;
}

#count_FilteredData {
  color: #498e88;
}

#filter-button {
  width: 100%;
}

#filter_section {
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  /* background-color: #f1f1f1; */
  border: 1px solid #cfcfcf;
}


/*Curtosy of the fellow fiddler's code: http://jsfiddle.net/unLSJ/*/

pre {
  background-color: ghostwhite;
  border: 1px solid silver;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  margin: 20px;
}

.json-key {
  color: brown;
}

.json-value {
  color: navy;
}

.json-string {
  color: olive;
}


/*Update the scrollbar*/

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 7px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px rgb(255, 255, 255);
  border-radius: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(132, 144, 154);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0" />
  <title>JSON - Date Range Filter Concept</title>

  <!-- CSS  -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

  <link href="https://materializecss.com/templates/starter-template/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

  <link href="css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen,projection" />

</head>

<body>

  <nav class="light-blue lighten-1" role="navigation">
    <div class="nav-wrapper container"><a id="logo-container" href="#" class="brand-logo">JSON Date Range Filter</a>
      <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      </ul>

      <ul id="nav-mobile" class="sidenav">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      </ul>

      <a href="#" data-target="nav-mobile" class="sidenav-trigger">
        <i class="material-icons">menu</i>
      </a>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="container">

    <div class="section">

      <!--   Raw Data Section   -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col s12">
          <div class="icon-block">
            <h4 class="center">Raw Data <small id="count_RawData">(0)</small></h4>
            <pre id="view_rawData" class="light">
              Your raw data will be previewed here
            </pre>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!--Filter Form-->
      <div class="row center" id="filter_section">
        <div class="input-field col s6">
          <input id="date_from" type="text" placeholder="From" class="datepicker">
        </div>
        <div class="input-field col s6">
          <input id="date_to" type="text" placeholder="To" class="datepicker">
        </div>
        <button id="filter-button" class="btn-large waves-effect waves-light">Filtra</button>
      </div>

      <!--   Filtered Data Section   -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col s12">
          <div class="icon-block">
            <h4 class="center">Filtered Data <small id="count_FilteredData">(0)</small></h4>
            <pre id="view_filteredData" class="light">
              Your final data will be previewed here
            </pre>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <br><br>
  </div>

</body>

</html>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://materializecss.com/templates/starter-template/js/init.js"></script>
```