# Can't get the code to get difference between 2 dates in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date, datediff

I need a user input for 2 dates, and get the difference between them, and if it is more than 14 days, throw an error.
Help appreciated
The date is in the format `yyyy/mm/dd`

Also, I want to match the pattern of the date to check if it is valid, I have done everything, month and year, except the day, it accepts days from 32-39 too, 
what should I do to correct it?

Comment: what do you have no far?

Comment: How are you getting this input? Select boxes, custom ui?

Comment: i am getting the input from input boxes and i am trying to find a code for perl script as it goes to ny database

Answer (score 2):

Assuming date1 and date2 are both [Date](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp) Objects.  Here's how you'd find if there was a 14 day difference between the two.

```
Math.abs(+date1 - (+date2)) > 12096000000
```

There are 12096000000 milliseconds in 14 days.

14 days x 24 hours x 60 minutes x 60 seconds x 1000 ms

There's an SO question which addresses validating dates from user inputs [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73971/using-javascript-how-do-i-make-sure-a-date-range-is-valid).

Comment: i am not sure if they are plain javascript objects, however, i have defined them as date1=newDate and date2=new Date, and thanx for quick reply

Comment: Yea those are plain date object - didn't mean to cause confusion.

Comment: i am getting the input using dicument.getelementbyid, and the link that you have shown doesnt take it that way,it already has then input

Answer (score 1):

For two dates dateA and dateB, the difference in days in Javascript is:

`daysDifference = Math.round((dateA - dateB)/(1000*60*60*24));`

Check the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/panda2005/YHEMr/15/) for a working example.

Comment: i am getting the input from input boxes and i am trying to find a code for perl script as it goes to ny database