# Comparing Datepicker Dates Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I'm trying to compare two `datepicker` dates and see if they are more than 7 days apart.

How would I do this?

I would normally just see if their difference is greater than 7, but that won't account for months and such.

Here is my code:

```
var datepickerBegin = $("#datepicker_start").val();
var datepickerEnd = $("#datepicker_to").val();

if (datepickerBegin - datepickerEnd > 7) { 
    alert('more than a week apart!') 
}
```

Any tips??

Comment: this seems to be the same question more or less - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/73971/using-javascript-how-do-i-make-sure-a-date-range-is-valid

Comment: When I try to utilize his solution, the 'difference' variable is NaN. Am I lost on something? I just want to see if it is indeed seven days apart

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use `$("#datepicker_xxx").datepicker("getDate")` to get the picked date as a `Date`. Then it's just a matter of

```
end - begin > 7 * 86400 * 1000
```

Answer (score 2):

// Check the date range, 86400000 is the number of milliseconds in one day

```
var difference = (datepickerEnd- datepickerBegin ) / (86400000 * 7);
if (difference < 0) {
  alert("The start date must come before the end date.");
  return false;
}

if (difference <= 1) {
  alert("The range must be at least seven days apart.");
  return false;
}

return true;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this, DatePicker has a handy formatDate function which i've used to compare mm/dd/yy dates:

```js
$.datepicker.formatDate("dd/mm/yy",new Date("09/01/2014")) < $.datepicker.formatDate("dd/mm/yy", new Date("10/01/2014")); // Returns true
$.datepicker.formatDate("dd/mm/yy",new Date("10/01/2014")) < $.datepicker.formatDate("dd/mm/yy", new Date("10/01/2014")); // Returns false
$.datepicker.formatDate("dd/mm/yy",new Date("11/01/2014")) < $.datepicker.formatDate("dd/mm/yy", new Date("10/01/2014")); // Returns false
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var datepickerBegin = $("#datepicker_start").val(); // lets, returning in mm/dd/yy format
var datepickerEnd = $("#datepicker_to").val(); // lets, returning in mm/dd/yy format

if ( ($.datepicker.parseDate('mm/dd/yy', datepickerBegin) -  $.datepicker.parseDate('mm/dd/yy', datepickerEnd)) > 7) {
alert('more than a week apart!') ;
}
```

Hope it should work. Thanks. For more [check it](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/parseDate) out.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#txtFromDate").datepicker({
        minDate: 0,
        maxDate: "+60D",
        numberOfMonths: 2,
        onSelect: function(selected) {
          $("#txtToDate").datepicker("option","minDate", selected)
        }
    });
    $("#txtToDate").datepicker({ 
        minDate: 0,
        maxDate:"+60D",
        numberOfMonths: 2,
        onSelect: function(selected) {
           $("#txtFromDate").datepicker("option","maxDate", selected)
        }
    });  
});
```

From: `<input type="text" id="txtFromDate" />`

To: `<input type="text" id="txtToDate" />`

Comment: Try to post your answer as code by indenting it with at least 4 spaces. It will be better readable then.

Answer (score 0):

this is working perfectly

```
function checkDateDifference(startDate, endDate) {
    startDate = $.datepicker.parseDate('mm/dd/yy', startDate);
    endDate = $.datepicker.parseDate('mm/dd/yy', endDate);

    var difference = (endDate - startDate) / (86400000);
    alert(difference)
    if (difference < 0) {
        showError("The start date must come before the end date.");
        return false;
    }
    return true;

}
```