# Results between two dates

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I would like to display the difference between two dates:

```
 date_debut<input type="text"name="date_debut" id="datepicker">
</br>

date fin<input type="text"name="date_fin"id="datepicker2">
</br>

nombre jour <input type="text"name="nombre_jour">
</br>
```

I want to enter the date start and end date and affect me in the number of days - the difference of two dates.

I made a small script, but it does not work. I'm a beginner to JavaScript and I had no time to learn JavaScript.

Here is the script I have made:

```
$('#datepicker, #datepicker2').datepicker();

$('button').click(function () {
    var start = $('#datepicker').val(),
        end = $('#datepicker2').val();

    var diffInDays = moment(end).diff(moment(start), 'days');

    alert(diffInDays);
});
```

Comment: Always try to be precise, don't write: 'it does not work'. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

According to *[Comparing Datepicker Dates Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12821033/comparing-datepicker-dates-javascript/12821180#12821180)*, use `.datepicker("getDate")` instead of `.val()`  to get the date and then it should just be:

```
var days = (end - start) / (86400 * 1000)
```